# Aminoethyl or ethylamine?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, amines

[image]

I was trying to name the above compound which happens to be 3-(2-aminoethyl)-2-methylcyclohexan-1-ol.

On my first attempt, I had named it 3-(ethyl-2-amine)-2-methylcyclohexan-1-ol.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IUPAC rules use "aminoethyl" for such a group. This is copied from the IUPAC "blue book" which can be found online [here](https://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/79/r79_510.htm)

Rule 811.3 - An -NH2 group, when not the principal group, is named by the prefix "amino-".

Your original name is very close to what would be used if the N were attached to the ring and the ethyl attached to the N. That would be "3-ethylamino-2-methyl. . ." according to this rule:

811.4 - Radicals RNH-, R2N-, and are named as substituted amino groups by changing "ine'' of the amine to "ino".

Comment: Is it also true for other groups with prefixes like, hydroxyethyl instead of ethylol?

Comment: Yes, the equivalent group with an HO would be hydroxyethyl-. If the oxygen were attached to the ring and had an alkyl group attached to it (an ether), it is called "alkyloxy-". For common groups like ethyl and methyl, the "yl" is dropped and it is just "methoxy-" or "ethoxy-".

Comment: Please note that your link points to obsolete IUPAC recommendations from 1979.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not aware of the newest version being available online, and these rules haven't changed. If you have a link to the newest rules, please post it.